# Importing imdb dataset from keras dataset

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I get an error when trying to load keras imdb dataset
This is my code

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np

data = keras.datasets.imdb

(train_data, train_label), (test_data, test_label) = data.load_data(num_words=10000)
```

and this is the error I get

```
<string>:6: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/datasets/imdb.py:159: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray
  x_train, y_train = np.array(xs[:idx]), np.array(labels[:idx])
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/datasets/imdb.py:160: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray
  x_test, y_test = np.array(xs[idx:]), np.array(labels[idx:])
```

Comment: That looks like a warning

Answer (score 0):

```
VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray
```

These are deprecation Warnings can be ignored. These warnings won't stop executing rest of the code.

Comment: Yes that is true but when I execute the next line of code `word_index = imdb.get_word_index()` I get this error `NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-6bb83d261f26> in <module>
----> 1 word_index = imdb.get_word_index()

NameError: name 'imdb' is not defined
`

Comment: This import will help you, `from tensorflow.keras.datasets import imbd`. Thanks!